# How to check the size of an email maybe with or without attachment when it is received by fuglu scanner plugin?

Tags: python-3.x, email

Using Python code how to check the size of an email? It may contain an attachment or no attachment(s). In SMTP handshake the 'From' has an attribute 'SIZE' which is optional. Without parsing the entire mail for checking the attachment size, is it possible to check the size of the entire email? What is the specific code? When we use:
in the examine method of fuglu plugin, I wish to override as follows:

```
msg = suspect.get_original_source()
mail = email.message_from_string(msg.decode("latin-1"))
```

WE get string. whcih I convert using:

```
 mail_size = len(str(mail).encode('utf-8'))
```

Is this the right approach? Please advise.

Comment: What about using this :
````sys.getsizeof(mail)````

, its returns the size of the object in bytes.

Comment: @Pdeuxa Doesn't work for email Message object

Comment: https://goshippo.com/blog/measure-real-size-any-python-object/ here is a method someone wrote to measure an iterable object size. Hope this helps